# Что означает запись >> или << в коде

Tags: c++

К примеру есть участки кода, подобные этим:

```
d[1 << i][i] = 1;

if (!((mask >> j) & 1) && g[i][j])
    d[mask ^ (1 << j)][j] += d[mask][i];
```

Что означают вот эти знаки **>>**, **<<**, **^**, **&** ?

И где можно почитать литературу про подобное?

И как это применяется в олимпиадных задачах?

Comment: Это бинарные операторы, работа с байтами. В данном случае это сдвиг влево или в право. Можно почитать в любой книге по СИ, тут есть примеры с таблицами https://radio-blogs.ru/blog/mikrokontrollery/operacii-bitovogo-sdviga-mikrokontrollerov

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> где почитать:

в абсолютно любой книге по с/с++ в первых главах, где описываются арифметические и логические операции. `>>` называется "оператор сдвига влево". `<<` называется "оператор сдвига вправо". `^` называется "исключающее или". Если в книге этого нет, выкидывайте такую книгу.

> где применяется

Операторы сдвига применяют в "олимпиадных задачах" для быстрого умножения/деления на степени двойки (и не только). Но современные компиляторы часто сами могут это сделать не хуже.

А еще операторы сдвига в С++ являются перегруженными операторами для некоторых классов. Например для `cout` и `cin` и позволяют делать ввод-вывод более "человечным".

К примеру конструкция `1 << i` очень популярна, если нужно получать степени двойки (очень быстро). `1 << 2 = 4 = 2 в степени 2`, `1 << n = 2 в степени n`.

Comment: Операторы сдвига применяются для выполнения умножения на степени двойки тогода, когда множитель является run-time значением, т.е. компилятор не может знать, что это степень двойки. Если же множитель - константа времени компиляции, то замена такого умножения на сдвиг - яркий пример "пионэрской оптимизации" в наивном студенческом коде, от которой нет никакой пользы и в которой нет никакого смысла.

Answer (score 11):

Попробую объяснить немного неформально, что означает << и >>. Например у нас есть такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main ()
{
  char a = 5 << 2;
  printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

У нас есть число 5 в десятичной системе счисления. Если его перевести в двоичную, будет: 0000 0101. Теперь берём и "сдвигаем" это двоичное представление влево на 2 позиции, добавляя справа нули: 0001 0100. А теперь переведём обратно получившееся двоичное число в десятичную систему счисления: 20. Если скомпилировать данный код и запустить, будет выведено: 20. Аналогично и для операции >>, только сдвиг вправо.

Answer (score 4):

Это бинарные операторы.

<< >> - Операторы сдвига.

& - Побитовое "И"

| - Побитовое "ИЛИ"

^ - Исключающее "ИЛИ"

~ - Оператор дополнения.

Подробнее об бинарных операторах и операциях можно почитать тут:
[Habrahabr.ru](http://habrahabr.ru/post/134557/) - Очень доступно описано.