# Что означает эта строка?

Tags: c++

```
int a = b << 1;
```

Comment: a = b сдвинутое на 1 бит влево

Comment: Если b целое, то

  a = b * 2;

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/240726/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5/240733#240733

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берется значение переменной b (я так понимаю, это целочисленная переменная), производится битовый сдвиг на одну позицию влево и полученным значением инициируется новая переменная a.

Answer (score 4):

Битовый сдвиг - [wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3)

если говорить грубо:

```
a<<b равно a*(2^b)

a>>b равно a/(2^b)
```