# Что такое >> в c++

Tags: c++, синтаксис

Здравствуйте, не могу это загуглить. Есть код программы.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus"); // корректное отображение Кириллицы
char buff[50];// Создает обьект типа Чар
ifstream fin("cppstudio.txt"); Создает обьект типа ifstream  и передает в конструктор название файла 

fin >> buff; // а вот эта строчка не понятна, как это работет ? что значит >>


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если совсем просто, то >> позволяет считать данные из файла(cppstudio.txt) в массив buff.

Comment: я попробовал в Гугл вбить: `c++ >>`. Одна из ссылок: [Что означает запись >> или << в коде](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/240726/23044)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что означает запись >> или << в коде](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/240726/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: @jfs не дубликат ни разу (пока что). Там была речь про арифметический оператор, а тут - про его перегруженную версию для ввода-вывода. Несмотря на похожесть, вопросы *совсем* не пересекаются.

Comment: @PavelMayorov нет, вопрос общий. Один и тот же оператор может разные действия выполнять в зависимости от типов. К примеру, принятый ответ явно упоминает cin/cout. Если необходимо, можно задать вопрос: «что делает ">>" для ifstream»

Comment: @jfs это значит что этот оператор перегружается в ifstream ?

Comment: @jfs вопрос - это заголовок с текстом, а не один только заголовок

Comment: @jfs если вам кажется, что у двух вопросов заголовки недопустимо похожи - предлагаю дописать заголовки

Comment: @PavelMayorov SO не разрешает вопросы с одинаковыми заголовками. Если автор вопроса не считает свой вопрос дубликатом, то следует более специфичный заголовок ему сделать, чтобы отразить действительный/желаемый вопрос.

Comment: @Accami вы даже сами можете >> оператор определить для желаемых типов. Вот [пример кода для << и вектора](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/629010/23044)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это помещение символов из файла cppstudio.txt в символный массив char buff[50]

Comment: Меня интересует каким именно образом происходит присваивание? Спасибо

Comment: @Accami внутренностями системной библиотеки